# Can I call a subclass' private method from its parent class?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, subclass, private, superclass

After reading about Ruby's access controls, I understand that a private method may only be called, implicitly, from within a class and within that class' subclasses.  I have an example, though, where a class seems to be calling a private method `default_chain` on its subclasses, and it still works.  Check out the following code (adapted from Sandi Metz' [Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby](https://www.poodr.com/)):

```
class Bicycle
    attr_reader :chain

    def initialize(args={})
        @chain = args[:chain] || default_chain
    end

    def parts
        {
            chain: chain
        }
    end
end

class RoadBike < Bicycle
    def parts
        super.merge(
            handlebar_tape_color: "red"
        )
    end

    private

    def default_chain
        "21-speed"
    end
end

class MountainBike < Bicycle
    def parts
        super.merge(
            suspension: "Manitou Mezzer Pro"
        )
    end

    private

    def default_chain
        "10-speed"
    end
end


RoadBike.new.parts  # {:chain=>"21-speed", :handlebar_tape_color=>"red"}
MountainBike.new.parts  # {:chain=>"10-speed", :suspension=>"Manitou Mezzer Pro"}
```

What's going on?

Comment: You ought to include a credit to Sandi Metz for her code.

Comment: `private` isn’t about class boundaries. It means that one object cannot call another object‘s private method, even if they are the same class.

Comment: To add to the valid comment by Stefan: ".... unless you are invoking that private method using `send`,  i.e. instead of doing `foo.bar(baz)`, you call it as `foo.send(:bar,baz)`. Cases where it is advisable to do so, are pretty rare, so think twice before attempting such an approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting it wrong - in your example, there is no such a thing as the parent class calling children methods.

Methods/constants name lookup in Ruby always works "bottom up": first we check if the method is defined in object's class, then in object's class's superclass and so on (this is a *huge* simplification because Ruby's object model is more complicated, more on this later). So, in your example things happen in roughly the following order:

1. When you call `RoadBike.new` runtime checks if there is an `initialize` methods defined for the class RoadBike. There is no, so we use the implementation defined for its parent class - `Bycicle` (but the execution context stays the same - it is still `RoadBike` instance)
2. When executing `Bycicle#initialize` runtime encounters another method call - `default_chain`. At this moment we start method name resolving in the very same manner - starting from the RoadBike context. Does `RoadBike` have its own implementation of `default_chain`? Yes, it does, so we simply call it.

The following baby example makes it crystal clear, hopefully:

```
class Parent
  def initialize
    puts "Parent Initializer is called"
    a
    b
  end

  def a
    puts "Parent a is called"
  end

  def b
    puts "Parent b is called"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def b
    puts "Child b is called"
  end
end

pry(main)> Child.new
Parent Initializer is called
Parent a is called
Child b is called
```

In reality the methods/constants resolution machinery is more complicated(includes so-called singleton classes). This is a bigger topic that will not fit nicely in SO answer, so I *strongly* recommend reading "[Metaprogramming Ruby 2](https://pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr2/metaprogramming-ruby-2/)" by Paolo Perotta where this model is wery well explained in great details from the very practical point of view.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  Thank you!